# If x is a reference to unique_ptr, then *x is "reference to element pointed to"?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, reference, unique-ptr

refPtrInt is a reference to pointer:

`int *& refPtrInt;`

Is `*refPtrInt` an `int` or a reference to an `int`?

EDIT:
Thank you for your answers about `refPtrInt`.
Actually, my original question is about this snippet from Stroustrup (A Tour of C++, section 5.5):

```
template<typename C, typename Oper>
void for_all(C& c, Oper op) // assume that C is a container of pointers
{
    for (auto& x : c)
    op(*x); // pass op() a reference to each element pointed to
}
vector<unique_ptr<Shape>> v;
// populate v with some kinds of Shape
for_all(v, [](Shape& s){ s.draw(); });
```

The comment "`pass op() a reference to each element pointed to`" is from Bjarn Stroustrup too. So, `*x` is apparently a reference to a `Shape`, when `x` is a reference to a `unique_ptr<Shape>`... Is that correct?

Comment: Hint: a reference can usually be thought of as another name for an existing object, and not a new object by itself.

Comment: Note that this question is [easy to test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c517083a24fae1cf) with a compiler.

Comment: @chris that tests the behaviour of `decltype` and also doesn't answer the question  (someone might conclude from the asserts passing that `*r` has type `int&` when in fact it doesn't)

Comment: @M.M, Fair point. There are additional considerations.

Answer (score 4):

There's no difference. Formally, expressions can't have reference type. Less formally, we could describe any expression as *referring to* an object. This usage is what appears in the textbook you quoted.

Formally, the expression `*refPtrInt` has type `int`, and its value category is *lvalue*, and it designates an `int` object.

`x` has type `unique_ptr<Shape>`. This means that [`*x`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*) calls the overloaded operator function:

```
typename std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type std::unique_ptr::operator*() const;
```

This is a function with return type `Shape&`.  It's common to say "The function returns a reference to `Shape`", but also important to understand that when the function call is used in an expression, the result (`*x` here) is an expression of type `Shape` and value category *lvalue*.

Answer (score 1):

It is `int`. The "reference" bit is irrelevant. You are derferencing the pointer and it points to `int`.